# PHP Variables for class wont work

Tags: php, php-5.3

I need help with php. I have a script that i need it to include a file.
Here is what i want to do

```
class example{
var $firstname = file_get_contents("myfirstname.txt");
var $lastname = file_get_contents("lastname.txt");
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like a back tick is messing with your markup.

Comment: @Daedalus, that was from stackoverflow markup (i  missed removing it when i removed the others)

Comment: Why would you want to instantiate a class in this manner?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a function like `file_get_contents` on a variable declaration inside a class. You could assign the values in the constructor:

```
class Example{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;

    function Example() {
        $this->firstname = file_get_contents("myfirstname.txt");
        $this->lastname = file_get_contents("lastname.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in PHP > 5

```
class Example{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;

    function __construct() {
        $this->firstname = file_get_contents("myfirstname.txt");
        $this->lastname = file_get_contents("lastname.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize class members that way.

Check the manual: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

You can only initialize class members with constant values.